# Properties : Private ready-only backing field vs. auto-implemented + constructor

Tags: c#

```
private readonly PlayerCollection players = new PlayerCollection();

public PlayerCollection Players { get { return players; } }
```

or

```
public PlayerCollection Players { get; private set; }

public MyClass()
{
    Players = new PlayerCollection();
}
```

Which would be preferable? Is there a context where one the of two ways is best suited?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the first way has the advantage that the field is `readonly`, so you can't set it again elsewhere in the class; the second way has the advantage that it isn't, so you can. To my mind, that's a good way to decide between them - do you want the field to be `readonly`? If so, first way; if not, second way.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case the compiler will ensure that the value can't change even from inside `MyClass`. Otherwise it's probably a wash, pick which you like better.

Answer (score 0):

Use the auto-implementation. You have to initialize readonly within the constructor, and there's almost never any use of using both private and readonly in conjunction with one another.

At least the auto-implementation solution lets you initialize outside the constructor, and still only allows assignment from within itself.

Comment: I have to disagree on "there's almost never any use of using both private and readonly in conjunction with one another", since it's really useful to prevent yourself from changing the value of an object (when it's private). Actually I would say that the public-readonly combination is less useful, since you rarely want public fields anyway (properties usually being more appropriate).

Comment: I use `private readonly` all the time for "constants" that can't be known at compile time like cache keys or font objects.

Answer (score 0):

From the caller's perspective, there is no difference between the two. However, in the first example, no one (not even MyClass) can set Players to a new PlayerCollection outside of the constructor. If you want the compiler to enforce this restriction, use (1). Otherwise, use (2).